# No module named 'ogr'

Tags: python, virtualenv, gdal, ogr, osgeo

I followed this tutorial (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/124420) to install gdal in a virtualenv. It seemed to work since I didn't get `No module named 'osgeo'` anymore when trying to import gdal.

But now I'm getting this error:

```
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/my-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py",
line 1468, in <module>
    import ogr
ImportError: No module named 'ogr'
```

I checked this directory, and it have the `ogr.py` file along with the `gdal.py` file.

Anyone know how to fix this? I'm almost trying to install it all again (not an easy task)

**EDIT:** In a shell inside my venv, I can do `from osgeo import ogr` but when I try `from osgeo import gdal` it gives the same error, when gdal try to `import ogr`, this means they are both in the osgeo module, but gdal can't "see" ogr for some reason I can't figure out

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70020/no-ogr-module-despite-having-gdal-installed

Comment: Sounds like you installed a Python 2 package on Python 3.

Comment: @alfasin already tried all answers for that, but the Anaconda one is not what I'm meant to use...

Comment: @user2357112 is it? And if it is, would it cause such a strange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled "pygdal" and did it manually as this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29096) says. Downloading "gdal" via `pip download gdal` and running `python setup.py install --install-headers=<path/to/gdal_headers>`